# Changing cell in GridView by vlidation

Tags: winforms, gridview, .net-4.0, devexpress, cell

I have a `GridView` and I want when I change a cell to see if its new value is valid by mine function `ValidateValue(string aValue)` and if it is valid - to store the new value and old value as a pair in `Struct S {string old,new};`  How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the GridView's ValidatingCell event for this purpose.  Here is some sample code showing how to obtain new and old edit values:

```
private void gridView1_ValidatingEditor(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e) {
    BaseEdit edit = (sender as GridView).ActiveEditor;
    object oldValue = edit.OldEditValue;
    object newValue = e.Value;
}
```